# IntelliJ: disable spell checking for dedicated file / folder

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

how can we disable spell-checking for a single file or folder in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest and most flexible way, I've found is to define a new scope (*File Settings* - *Appearence & Behaviour* - *Scopes*).
And then use this for the Spell-check inspection (*File* - *Settings* - *Editor* - *Inspections* - *Spelling*)

Answer (score -1):

You can

> Mark as Plain Text

a folder from its context menu; e.g. right click the folder and select **Mark as Plain Text**.  This will disable "inspections and code completion", which may be more of a broadsword approach than you're looking for.

Reference: [JetBrains IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/excluding-files-from-project.html).

You can also [add words to the dictionary](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/spellchecking.html), disable the spellchecker on a per-project level (in WebStorm it's **Project Settings > Editor > Inspections > Spelling > Typo**), or (if you're looking for more of a scalpel) even [manually configure Inspection Severities](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-inspection-severities.html#d1827280e64).

Comment: Plain text files are still spell checked.

Comment: There is no "Mark as Plain Text" option in this menu